# which apk runs on the Android device ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk, android-install-apk

Which apk file runs on the Android device after the cli command `ionic run android`? Where can I find this file inside my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact path can be a little different per Cordova version, but if you want to get the exact path, take a look at the output when running `ionic run android`. At the end you'll see something like:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 10.66 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /home/myuser/Documents/Projects/mysuperapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Using apk: /home/myuser/Documents/Projects/mysuperapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
Installing app on device...
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

Notice the output with the text `Using apk:`. This display's the complete path to the APK used installing on the device. In my case */home/myuser/Documents/Projects/mysuperapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk*

**EDIT:**

If you want to create an APK for production usage / release into the Play Store, make sure to follow the next steps: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Comment: Curios, why is the apk file named android-debug? Is this not the production ready file? Am I doing something wrong, like to bundle it for running not testing.

Comment: We are using Ionic on top of Cordova and they released some documentation on how to generate a signed APK for Play Store: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Comment: We as well are using the same stack, thank you for quick response and a perfect one too!

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's `platforms\platform\CordovaApp-debug.apk` if you haven't changed any additional options.

Where `platform` is `android` or `ios`, depending again on your settings.